# How to show Legend of Apex Charts (ReactJS) even if there is no series data available

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I am using line-apex Charts in ReactJs. If there is no data available then legend for Y-Axis is invisible. And if data is available they will show up. I want legend to be displayed even if there is no data in series.
Alternatives I tried out: If there is no data in DB, send seriesData with 0 Values, it will show the point on the graph with 0 value and legend will be available. But, I want to get rid of that point.

```
getOptions() {
    return {
      chart: {
        height: 200,
        type: "line",
        stacked: false,
      },
      colors: this.themes[this.props.theme],
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      stroke: {
        width: [3.5, 3.5],
      },
      xaxis: {
        categories: this.props.xCategories,
        labels: {
          style: {
            color: "#263238",
          },
        },
      },
      yaxis: [
        {
          axisTicks: {
            show: true,
          },
          axisBorder: {
            show: false,
          },
          labels: {
            style: {
              colors: this.themes[this.props.theme][0],
              fontWeight: "bold",
            },
          },
          tooltip: {
            enabled: false,
          }
        },
        {
          seriesName: "Revenue",
          opposite: false,
          axisTicks: {
            show: true,
          },
          axisBorder: {
            show: false,
          },
          labels: {
            style: {
              colors: this.themes[this.props.theme][1],
              fontWeight: "bold",
            },
          },
        },
      ],
      legend: {
        position: "top",
        horizontalAlign: "left",
        offsetX: -15,
        fontWeight: "bold",
      }
    }
  }
```

And below is the render method:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>      
        <Chart
          options={this.getOptions()}
          series={this.props.seriesData}
          type='line'
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few properties that determine whether the legend should be shown in different circumstances. There's information available in the [ApexCharts documentation](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/legend/), but here's an overview:

---

**showForSingleSeries**

default: false

This will determine if the legend should be shown even if there is just one series being displayed on the graph.

---

**showForNullSeries**

default: true

This will determine whether series that contain only null values are hidden.

---

**showForZeroSeries**

default: true

This will determine whether series that contain only zero values are hidden.

---

In your case, you'll want to make sure first of all that the `showForSingleSeries` is set to `true` to ensure that the legend is always shown. Secondly, rather than returning a series that contains a zero value, you can return either an empty array or an array containing `null` elements.

Finally, in order for the legend to show up when using your code, I had to add a `series` property to the `options` object. This is because the legend won't display unless it has any series names to show - it doesn't know the names of the series you'll be providing it with unless you specify it.

```
var options = {
  ...
  series: [
    {
      name: "Revenue",
      data: []
    }
  ]
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will definitely try this out !!!